# Trying to generate a string of text

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to use mathematica to generate some code that I can use in excel.

The goal is to have something like:

> IF(BB32="",CA31,0)+IF(BB34="",CA33,0)+IF(BB36="",CA35,0)+IF(BB38="",CA37,0)+IF(BB40="",CA39,0)+IF(BB42="",CA41,0)+ ....

I have written the following code:

```
Table[StringForm["+IF(BB`1`=\"\",CA`2`,0)", i, i - 1], {i, 44, 118,2}]
```

This seems to get me really close, but it adds commas between the terms. I could use a find and replace rule to remove the commas, but that would also get rid of the internal commas I want to keep.

I'm not sure what is the best way to go from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StringForm` prints the text for the expression, but it doesn't create strings. Instead, use `StringTemplate` or `TemplateApply`. Try this to make the Excel code:

```
StringRiffle[Table[StringTemplate["IF(BB`1`=\"\",CA`2`,0)"][i, i-1], {i,44,118,2}], "+"]
```

`StringRiffle` joins the strings from `Table` together and inserts "+" between them.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, and I learned about StringRiffle to boot.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to use `StringRiffle`:

```
StringRiffle[IntegerString[{#, # - 1}] & /@ Range[44, 118, 2], 
  "+", {"IF(BB", "=\"\",CA", ",0)"}]
```

[image]